# Problems with OpenOCD under Eclipse Neon.2 (release 4.6.2)

Tags: eclipse, stm32, openocd

I have been trying to establish connection between STM3220G-EVAL board and OpenOCD debugger under Eclipse Neon.2 (release 4.6.2) running on Windows 7 PC.
My *Debug Configuration* looks like: [image]. The problem is that I still receive following Error Message: [image]. I have found in another thread that this message is due to the missing line `-f board\stm32f4discovery.cfg` so I have appended it. But the result is still the same. Does anybody know what the reason could be? Thanks for any suggestions.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set this option in the GDB section, not OpenOCD section. Check "Start OpenOCD locally" and move the "-f board/stm32f4discovery.cfg" line to "Config options" instead.

Comment: Thank you Jacek for your reaction. I have applied the changes but I have received another error message (please see the figure in my question).

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind is checking whether your OpenOCD path points to correct destination. I've just checked it myself and I get the exact same message when the path is incorrect. I'd also check permissions.

Comment: I have checked Preferences->Run/Debug->OpenOCD. The path was actually set in bad manner. I have corrected it but the result is still the same. You have mentioned the permissions. Can you tell me what do you mean exactly? Thanks.

Comment: By that I meant to check whether you have rights to access/execute this executable. Probably the easiest way is to copy-paste the Eclipse command directly and see whether you get some output/error from openocd.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse Neon.2 is broken for hardware debugging. Your only option is to downgrade to Neon.1.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=509812